# How can I show that $e^{-in\pi}=(-1)^{n}, e^{-i\pi n/2}=(-i)^{n}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I practice some examples from a digital signal processing book. 

They used that $e^{-in\pi}=(-1)^{n}, e^{-i\pi n/2}=(-i)^{n}$. How did they come up with that?
Of course I know Euler identity but I can't sometimes figure out how to come up with this relations.

Comment: Perhaps by $j$ you mean $i$?

Comment: We use in DSP j as imaginary unit :)

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake, $j$ is commonly used in the electrical engineering world (e.g., digital signal processing) to represent the imaginary unit.

Comment: Ahh, sorry! I did not know that!

Answer (score 2):

From Euler's identity, $$e^{iy}=cosy+isiny$$

 For $y=-n\pi$ and the fact that $\cos (n\pi)=(-1)^n, \sin (n\pi)=0$ you have these relations.

Answer (score 2):

[Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) says $e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta$.

Therefore, $e^{-in\pi} = e^{i(-n\pi)} = \cos(-n\pi) + i\sin(-n\pi)$.  Then using basic trig (unit circle) you end up with $(-1)^n$.  Similar argument for $e^{-in\pi/2}$.